# How to use FastDateFormat in java to find if current date is between given dates?

Tags: java, date

I have a method which accepts 2 date strings- startDateString and endDateString.
It is in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" format.
Now I have to return true of today(current date) is in between the given dates otherwise return false.

I have to use FastDateFormat.

Please suggest.

```
public boolean effective(String startDateString, String endDateString) {
...
}
```

Comment: This would have two parts: 1) Parse the date strings; 2) Compare today's date to those dates. Which parts don't you know how to do?

Comment: @AndyTurner I am not getting how to use fastdateformat. I need help how to parse dates. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, if all dates are formatted properly into this particular format and are reasonably contemporary dates, you can just compare them as strings.

Comment: How about: `Date startDate = new FastDateFormat(<date format string>).parse(startDateString)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Date startDate = new FastDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateString); it says, the FastDateFormat has protected access.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am not getting how to do. Please suggest me with some code. Thanks

Comment: By the way, with modern Java you can parse without any Apache utility: `LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-01-23 12:34:56.123456789".replace( " " , "T" ) )`

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for `FastDateFormat` is [in the Apache Commons website](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html). That's always the first place to turn to when you are asked to use a particular class.

Now, `FastDateFormat` has a `protected` constructor. Instead of using its constructor, you are supposed to use one of the many `getInstance` static factory methods that give you a `FastDateFormat`:

```
FastDateFormat fullDateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

Now, if you are going to be using this format a lot, it makes sense to define it as a constant in your class:

```
public static final FastDateFormat FULL_DATE_FORMAT = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

Now, you can use this to parse your two date strings:

```
try {
    long startTime = FULL_DATE_FORMAT.parse( startDateString ).getTime();
    long endTime = FULL_DATE_FORMAT.parse( endDateString ).getTime();

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return currentTime >= startTime && currentTime < endTime;
} catch ( ParseException e ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Improperly formatted date", e );
}
```

Now, this tells you if the current time is between the two time stamps represented by those strings.

As I mentioned in the comments, in this specific format, because it arranges the date from the most significant field to the least significant in fixed sized fields, you can actually compare strings. Note that this is not exactly true - the milliseconds field is going to problematic unless you use the format `.SSS` instead of `.S` at the end. If the milliseconds part is not going to be significant in your context, this is how you would do this:

```
String currDate = FULL_DATE_FORMAT.format( new Date() );
return currDate.compareTo( startDateString ) >= 0
       && currDate.compareTo( endDateString ) < 0;
```

Note: if you are working in Java 8, it's recommended to use its `java.time` package for dates and times rather than the `Date`, `DateFormat` and `Calendar` family of classes. Its formatters are immutable and thread-safe so you wouldn't need the `FastDateFormat` class.